# OpenSSL code works natively but as DLL causes OPENSSL_Uplink: no OPENSSL_Applink

Tags: c#, c++, dll, mono, openssl

This will hardly get any answer but let's try anyway. Also I might just have done some really basic thing wrong... but anyway:

I have to use some OpenSSL functions for AES/RSA encrypt/decrypt with PHP (just telling this so if you know some headace-saving alternatives, you know...) with Mono. Since OpenSSL.NET first doesn't work with Mono and second it doesn't receive support any longer, I've been forced to port the functions I needed directly from C OpenSSL to a DLL and call these functions from C#, which is a pain by itself.

As you'd may notice, the encrypt/decrypt functions are directly <s>stolen AHEM</s> taken from [the wiki.](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption)

The .h file is:

```
#pragma once

#include <comdef.h>
#include <comutil.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/applink.c>

#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

namespace OpenSSL
{
    extern "C" { EXPORT int NumericTest(int a, int b); }
    extern "C" { EXPORT BSTR StringTest(); }
    extern "C" { EXPORT BSTR StringTestReturn(char *toReturn); }

    extern "C" { EXPORT int Encrypt_AES_256_CBC(unsigned char *plaintext,
                                                int plaintext_len,
                                                unsigned char *key,
                                                unsigned char *iv,
                                                unsigned char *ciphertext); }

    extern "C" { EXPORT int Decrypt_AES_256_CBC(unsigned char *ciphertext,
                                                int ciphertext_len,
                                                unsigned char *key,
                                                unsigned char *iv,
                                                unsigned char *plaintext); }

    extern "C" { EXPORT void HandleErrors(); }
}
```

The .cpp file is:

```
#include "OpenSSL.h"

namespace OpenSSL
{
    void HandleErrors()
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

    void InitOpenSSL()
    {
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
        OPENSSL_config(NULL);
    }

    int NumericTest(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    BSTR StringTest()
    {
        return ::SysAllocString(L"StringTest successful!");
    }

    BSTR StringTestReturn(char *toReturn)
    {
        _bstr_t bstrt(toReturn);
        bstrt += " (StringTestReturn)";

        strcpy_s(toReturn, 256, "StringTestReturn");
        return bstrt;
    }

    int Encrypt_AES_256_CBC(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
    {
        InitOpenSSL();

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

        int len;

        int ciphertext_len;

        /* Create and initialise the context */
        if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) HandleErrors();

        /* Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
        * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
        * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
        * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
        * is 128 bits */
        if (1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
            HandleErrors();

        /* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
        * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
        */
        if (1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
            HandleErrors();
        ciphertext_len = len;

        /* Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
        * this stage.
        */
        if (1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) HandleErrors();
        ciphertext_len += len;

        /* Clean up */
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

        return ciphertext_len;
    }

    int Decrypt_AES_256_CBC(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key,
                unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext)
    {
        InitOpenSSL();

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

        int len;

        int plaintext_len;

        /* Create and initialise the context */
        if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) HandleErrors();

        /* Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
        * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
        * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
        * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
        * is 128 bits */
        if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
            HandleErrors();

        /* Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
        * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
        */
        if (1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
            HandleErrors();
        plaintext_len = len;

        /* Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
        * this stage.
        */
        if (1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)) HandleErrors();
        plaintext_len += len;

        /* Clean up */
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

        return plaintext_len;
    }
}
```

**Note how these functions had been tested and works perfectly fine on a C++ console application**

Last but not least, the C# code I've been using for testing purposes:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace OpenSSLTests
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    class OpenSSL
    {
        const string OPENSSL_PATH = "(here i putted my dll file path (of course in the program i putted the real path, but not here))";

        [DllImport(OPENSSL_PATH, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int NumericTest(int a, int b);

        [DllImport(OPENSSL_PATH, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public static extern string StringTest();

        [DllImport(OPENSSL_PATH, EntryPoint = "StringTestReturn", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public static extern string StringTestReturn(StringBuilder toReturn);

        [DllImport(OPENSSL_PATH, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int Encrypt_AES_256_CBC(StringBuilder plainText,
                                                    int plaintext_len,
                                                    StringBuilder key,
                                                    StringBuilder iv,
                                                    StringBuilder ciphertext);

        [DllImport(OPENSSL_PATH, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int Decrypt_AES_256_CBC(StringBuilder cipherText,
                                                    int ciphertext_len,
                                                    StringBuilder key,
                                                    StringBuilder iv,
                                                    StringBuilder plaintext);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("the numeric test result is: " + NumericTest(1, 2));
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("the string test result is: " + StringTest());
            Console.WriteLine();

            StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder(256);
            test.Append("test");
            Console.WriteLine("test is: " + test);
            Console.WriteLine();




            Console.WriteLine("Calling StringTestReturn...");
            string newTest = StringTestReturn(test);
            Console.WriteLine("test is now: " + test);
            Console.WriteLine("newTest is: " + newTest);
            Console.WriteLine();

            StringBuilder plainText = new StringBuilder(1024);
            plainText.Append("this is a really crashy test plz halp");

            StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder(1024);
            StringBuilder IV = new StringBuilder(1024);

            key.Append("randomkey12345asdafsEWFAWEFAERGERUGHERUIGHAEIRUGHOAEGHSD");
            IV.Append("ivtoUse1248235fdghapeorughèaerjèaeribyvgnèaervgjer0vriono");

            StringBuilder ciphredText = new StringBuilder(1024);

            int plainTextLength = Encrypt_AES_256_CBC(plainText, plainText.Length, key, IV, ciphredText);

            if (plainTextLength != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("encrypted text length: " + plainTextLength);
                Console.WriteLine("the encrypted text content is: " + ciphredText);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error encrypting\n");
            }

            StringBuilder decryptedText = new StringBuilder(1024);

            int decryptedTextLength = -1;
            try
            {
                decryptedTextLength = Decrypt_AES_256_CBC(ciphredText, ciphredText.Length, key, IV, decryptedText);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error during decryption");
            }

            if (decryptedTextLength != -1)
            {
                decryptedText[decryptedTextLength] = '\0';
                Console.WriteLine("decrypted text length: " + decryptedTextLength);

                try
                {
                    //here it crashes without even giving you the courtesy of printing anything. It just closes
                    Console.WriteLine("decrypted text is:     " + decryptedText);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error after decryption");
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

As you'd might expect, it shouldn't work. **Not exactly**. Or better: it doesn't work but the strange thing is the way it doesn't: unlike any other program i ever wrote or heard, when the program runs Visual Studio just opens a console window but just for an istant and then it self shuts down without even throwing an error. You know, like when you learn C# and write hello world but forget to add Console.ReadLine() at the end or system("PAUSE") in c++ so it closes in a second? The same thing.

However if i run it by pressing ctrl+F5 i get the console and the output will be:

```
the numeric test result is: 3

the string test result is: StringTest successful!

test is: test

Calling StringTestReturn...
test is now: StringTestReturn
newTest is: test (StringTestReturn)

encrypted text length: 48
the encrypted text content is: 9ïÅèSðdC1¦æÌ?
OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FFFFB388000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink
Premere un tasto per continuare . . . (press a key to finish in italian)
```

So the error is supposed to be that *OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FFFFB388000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink* and it throws it while i try to write the decrypted text.

According to the [documentation of the website](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG2), it happens if you forget to include applink.c to the code but as you can see it's right there in the .h file.

So how should i get rid of it? Including applink.c doesn't work.

I will sell my soul to you if you can get me out of this eternal hell.

Regards.

Comment: *"... but as DLL causes OPENSSL_Uplink: no OPENSSL_Applink"* - This is sometimes due to mixing and matching C/C++ runtimes. You should probably go back to the early steps in your project, and rebuild everything using the same C/C++ runtimes. Be sure Mono and other Windows-on-Linux projects are using the same version of the runtime. Also, avoid the distro's copy of OpenSSL-on-Windows, like Cygwin. Build OpenSSL yourself to ensure you get the right C/C++ runtime (this leads to a number of WTF? problems).

Comment: will give it a try. It might take 1 billion years through, since i'm super bad at installing stuff such as OpenSSL even with step by step tutorials XD

Answer (score 0):

Just include the applink.c in the main.c and don't include it in any another file!